# Nvidia gtx card stopped working, How may I diagnose the fault?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

My GTX 285 card has suddenly stopped working, I have tried inserting it in another system but does not show any display, someone suggested that i bake the card in an oven. but since it has worked properly from the past four years, is there any way that i can diagnose it and then try to fix it?

Comment: You don't have a diagram of the card so there is no way to confirm what is correct and what is incorrect.  You can bake it in the oven I suppose but that only addresses a specific problem.  Due to the age of the card the time spent trying to fix it might be better spent buying a $50 card that is 4x as powerful as the `GTX 285`

Comment: Obtain schematics of the video card and an electrical engineering degree (which will lead you to the discovery that it's basically unfixable), or skip that and buy a new graphics card.

Comment: Haha alright guys,  will do!